# IOS difference in using Compact Regular and Compact Any Size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I had made an application on ios for iphones portrait mode only by
using Compact Any Size Classes .. its working perfectly on types of phones.

But XCode storyboard prefers to use **compact Regular Size classes** for all iphone portrait mode.

I am unable to differenciate in them .. if I am using wrong size classes.
Please someone explain with detail and reasons that which size classes I should use.

I had Read that storyboards using Any| Any size classes will work on all screen sizes including iphone 6 plus and ipad devices.

So why should it not Compact| any will not preferrable to all iphones in portrait.
Please guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Compact Width | Regular Height** is the best suited SizeClass as per your requirement to handle all iPhone models with Portrait only mode.

Choosing a right Size class will allow to make xCode the best prediction about the screen on which the layout would be drawn. So Its better to be most accurate about it.

> From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/SelectingASizeClass.html
>
> For example, when you select Compact Width | Regular Height, changes
>   to layout constraints and views apply exclusively to iPhone devices in
>   portrait orientation.

[image]

---

**More Details:**

In fact, here is a nice pictorial view of size class usage:

[image]

Comment: i had already completed my project with compact regular size classes, but thanks. i found your answer very late. but thanks for details

Comment: i had founded some thing with compact regular size classes that when we use this layout some of auto layout constraint are stops working. like if we use UITableview and we want to calculate row size as per text in uilabel using constraint only then this will not work accordingly. We need to scroll the uitableview again and again for that. I don't know if it is an Apple bug or what. but this happens. For demo : Working ) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EIkjmOj3ImWXZjVFZMYXZmVGc/view?pref=2&pli=1 // Not working  ) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_EIkjmOj3ImMGRNOXU2RlNkWEk/view?pref=2&pli=1